# grub-mkimage with --prefix=(a UUID) instead of (hdx,gptx)?

Tags: grub2

This command works perfectly but I'm not comfortable using hd#,gpt# as these can change anytime I plug another drive in.  So I need this exact command except that the prefix has to be set by UUID instead of (hd#,gpt#).

```
grub-mkimage -o /path/to/mounted/esp/partition/EFI/prime_boot/bootx64.efi --format=x86_64-efi '--prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/prime_boot' ext2 part_gpt
```

I've tried various things UUID=9045-CF30, just 9045-CF30 and a few more.  Does anyone know the right way?

Comment: It's not possible using `--prefix`.

Comment: Using EFI64 has among its advantages that you don't run into the 640KB or so limitation that grub2 runs into on BIOS (it's actually just 400KB if bootstrapped by grldr, but I'm digressing). So on EFI64, by all means, [ab]use `grub-mkstandalone` which will include every GRUB module, theme, and font from the installation in a monolithic EFI file. It does this by setting up a memdisk, IIRC (samek as `grub-mkimage -m`). That way you don't have to worry about `prefix`, but you still have to worry about `root`.

Comment: There is one subtlety that the built-in config file (with `-c`) still can't contain menus, but the one on the memdisk can! There's still the disadvantage that it's not easy to edit--you have to regen the whole shebang. If you want to have easily editable config (without regen), there's no workaround for a proper `search` in the built-in (-c or -m) config file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include a `grub.cfg` file within your `bootx64.efi` and have grub find out the correct prefix. Your *early config file* would contain only:

```
search.fs_uuid 12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0 root
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Your `grub-mkimage` command should then read:

```
grub-mkimage -o /path/to/mounted/esp/partition/EFI/prime_boot/bootx64.efi -c early-config-file --format=x86_64-efi '--prefix=Dont-Care'  MODULES...(read below)....
```

Please note that this "early config" is *included* within `grubx64.efi`, so it does not need to be called `grub.cfg"` nor does it need to be included in the `/boot/efi/EFI/wherever/` directory. This is different from, among others, Ubuntu, where the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` is actually *read* - i.e. if you rename it, your system will not boot.

Then: the modules. In order to be able to use "search", you'll have to include more than just `ext2 part_gpt` as you do. The bare minimum for a plain ext4 formatted root filesystem seems to be `ext2 part_gpt search configfile test linux loadenv`. At least this worked for my setup - albeit with an error, complaining that no font could be loaded.

And in fact, Ubuntu itself includes more than 100 GRUB modules and a memdisk with a font. Yes, those are *inside* the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` file.

Comment: The reason Ubuntu includes a great number of GRUB modules in `grubx64.efi` is probably mostly related to Secure Boot. When Secure Boot is enabled, any data that is not loaded from validly signed PE-COFF `*.EFI` binary files will be marked as non-executable memory segments by the firmware. GRUB modules use ELF binary format, not PE-COFF, so the firmware won't know how to check their signatures. Any modules included in the `grubx64.efi` are covered by its signature, so for Secure Boot, essentially all the modules are packed into it.

Comment: 3rd line `configfile $prefix/grub.cfg` is auto generated according to the documentation, "After the embedded configuration file (if any) is executed, GRUB will load the ‘normal’ module (see normal), which will then read the real configuration file from $prefix/grub.cfg." So no need for that. In fact, it can lead to confusion if your grub.cfg is not a menu and returns instead of booting, because it will be executed twice in your setup.